# Navigation Link - Pass Specific Array Element To New View via NavigationLink & Lists

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, state, swiftui-navigationlink

I have an array titled **recipeArray** that is displayed in a list. When a list item is clicked, the user is taken to a new view titled **RecipeItemDetailView**. The array contains some default values as placeholders.

```
struct StoredRecipeModel: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var name: String
var recipeSteps: [String]
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var recipeArray: [StoredRecipeModel] = [StoredRecipeModel(name: "one", recipeSteps: ["step1 here", "step1b", "Step1c"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "two", recipeSteps: ["step2here"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "three", recipeSteps: ["Step3here"])]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(recipeArray, id: \.id) { index in NavigationLink(destination: RecipeItemDetailView(recipe: $recipeArray, listItem: ListIndex.init())) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(index.name)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In the **RecipeItemDetailView** (the view the user navigates to when clicking on a list item), I want to only display the data for a given element. For example, if the user clicks on the first item in the list (labeled "One"), I would only like to display the **recipeSteps** for that given element - in this case being ["step1 here", "step1b", "Step1c"].

My current code passes forward the entire array. Is there a way to only pass forward the elements tied to a given index - e.g. the index that is clicked on?

**EDIT - adding additional RecipeItemDetailView code**

import SwiftUI

struct RecipeItemDetailView: View {

```
@Binding var recipe: [StoredRecipeModel]
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
//@ObservedObject var listItem: ListIndex
var recipeDataToReturn = 0


var body: some View {
    
    var stored = [recipe[recipeDataToReturn].recipeSteps]
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List(stored[0], id: \.self) { index in Text(index)}
   
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    Button("print") {
                        print(stored)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the recipe and no Binding to it, it's very easy -- just pass the variable you get in the `List` closure to your detail view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var recipeArray: [StoredRecipeModel] = [StoredRecipeModel(name: "one", recipeSteps: ["step1 here", "step1b", "Step1c"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "two", recipeSteps: ["step2here"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "three", recipeSteps: ["Step3here"])]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(recipeArray, id: \.id) { recipe in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RecipeItemDetailView(recipe: recipe)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(recipe.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct RecipeItemDetailView : View {
    var recipe: StoredRecipeModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe.name)
    }
}
```

If you need a Binding, you can get that with the index:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var recipeArray: [StoredRecipeModel] = [StoredRecipeModel(name: "one", recipeSteps: ["step1 here", "step1b", "Step1c"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "two", recipeSteps: ["step2here"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "three", recipeSteps: ["Step3here"])]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(recipeArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RecipeItemDetailView(recipe: $recipeArray[index])) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(recipeArray[index].name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RecipeItemDetailView : View {
    @Binding var recipe: StoredRecipeModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe.name)
    }
}
```

Or, write a Binding to tie the id to the element:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var recipeArray: [StoredRecipeModel] = [StoredRecipeModel(name: "one", recipeSteps: ["step1 here", "step1b", "Step1c"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "two", recipeSteps: ["step2here"]), StoredRecipeModel(name: "three", recipeSteps: ["Step3here"])]
    
    func bindingForId(id: UUID) -> Binding<StoredRecipeModel> {
        .init {
            recipeArray.first(where: { $0.id == id}) ?? StoredRecipeModel(name: "", recipeSteps: [])
        } set: { newValue in
            recipeArray = recipeArray.map {
                return $0.id == id ? newValue : $0
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(recipeArray, id: \.id) { recipe in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RecipeItemDetailView(recipe: bindingForId(id: recipe.id))) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(recipe.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RecipeItemDetailView : View {
    @Binding var recipe: StoredRecipeModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe.name)
    }
}
```

**Update, based on comments:**

```
struct RecipeItemDetailView : View {
    @Binding var recipe: StoredRecipeModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(recipe.recipeSteps, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
                
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                        Button("print") {
                            print(recipe)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I do need a binding, so the first option cannot be used. As for the second two options, I receive errors with both. The first option I receive an error stating I should file a report as an error cannot be created. For the last approach, I receive the following error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<StoredRecipeModel>' to expected argument type 'Binding<[StoredRecipeModel]>'" - any thoughts?

Comment: In order to help, I'd have to know what errors they were... I had to stub out `StoredRecipeModel` because you didn't include it, so I'm guessing it has to do with that as all of the code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: I have added the additional code. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: So are the errors happening in `RecipeItemDetailView`? If you haven't changed it to accommodate just getting `@Binding var recipe: StoredRecipeModel` like in my code, there will definitely be problems...

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what `RecipeItemDetailView` may need to look like to avoid an error.